# AFrame - AR - GLTF not displaying

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

Testing A Frame for use with augmented reality (AR)

I have read through documentation and tested a small a-box which displays fine on top of the marker, but when I add a gltf model it wont load, I have tried the model on an online gltf viewer and it works fine, but it wont work on A Frame code?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-system@^1.4.x/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"
      data-component-description="Physics system for A-Frame VR, built on Cannon.js"
      data-component-names="dynamic-body,static-body,constraint"
      data-component-url="https://npmjs.com/package/aframe-physics-system"
      data-package-name="aframe-physics-system"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <!-- https://cdn.glitch.global/40131ca8-3d08-4bae-ad16-b96766757df7/kit.gltf?v=1668698450644 -->
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
  <script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

  <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="tree" src="https://cdn.glitch.me/c7d0d4e9-d04a-4e56-989f-c554ae50c253%2Fwindmilmaster4.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <!-- create your content here. just a box for now -->
      <a-entity>
        <a-box position="0 0 -2" material="opacity: 1;"></a-box>
        <a-entity gltf-model="##tree" scale=".02 .02 .02"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
      <a-marker-camera preset="hiro"></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would love to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Apologies after some time I have noticed some of the script werent upto date and more importantly were not inside of the